# compare two data.frame with diffrent number of row to return the same value that are contained in two data.frame

Tags: r

I have two data.frame with different number of rows and same columns like below:

data.frame1:

```
ID  Name    Target  mean    conc
SW2012  NRT N   12  1
SW2019  NRT N   43  10
SW2024  NRT A   23  10
SW2041  NRT N   10  1
SW2045  NRT N   3   1
```

data.frame2:

```
ID  Name    Target  mean    conc
SW2012  BTR N   12  1
SW2019  BTR A   42  1
SW2022  BTR A   11  10
SW2045  BTR A   12  10
```

now,I would like to find same ID and extract and merge them into a new data frame.I have been trying to use merge function but it gives me wrong answer. I would appreciate if some one help me. The desired output will be:

```
ID  Name    Target  mean conc   Name    Target  mean    conc
SW2012  BTR N   12  1           NRT     N   12  1
SW2019  BTR A   42  1           NRT     N   43  10
SW2045  BTR A   12  10          NRT     N   3   1
```

Comment: What was wrong with `merge(data.frame2,data.frame1,by='ID')`?

Comment: it should give me the same Id but they are more than the number of line that  I have.

Comment: I tried `merge` command as shown in the comment above, and it produced the proper answer for your sample data set.

Comment: I can explain,for example if I have data frame with 240 rows and data.frame2 with 230 rows.This function gives me 284 rows.i do not no why?!!!

Comment: Are the IDs unique within each data frame?

Comment: ooh,no they are not unique.Thanks Marat .

Comment: Is there any way,to remove rows where ID is duplicated, but conditional upon the conc value such that I calculate the mean of corresponding conc values for all duplicated ID.and keep it by the corresponding ID?

Comment: Sure, use `dplyr` functions `group_by` and `summarize`